# Different Predictions with same Keras CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I trained a CNN on 100x120 images, creating the following generators:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255)

#Apply them
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_data_dir,
    target_size=(parameters["img_width"], parameters["img_height"]),
    batch_size = parameters["batch_size"],
    class_mode= "categorical", 
    subset = "training", 
    color_mode = "rgb",
    seed = 42)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = test_data_dir,
    target_size = (parameters["img_width"], parameters["img_height"]),
    color_mode = "rgb",
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode = None,
    shuffle = False,
    seed = 41)
```

Hence, I test the performances on different images as:

```
# Method 1
test_generator.reset()
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator,verbose = 1, steps = 1)
predicted_class_indices = np.argmax(pred, axis = 1)

# Convert the dictionary
labels = (train_generator.class_indices)
labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
```

However, if I want to generate prediction on the same image using:

```
# Method 2
crop_img = cv2.resize(img,(100, 120))                        
crop_img = np.reshape(crop_img,[1, 100, 120, 3])
crop_img = crop_img.astype('float32')
crop_img /= 255

# ID
pred = model.predict(crop_img)
predicted_class_indices = np.argmax(pred, axis = 1)
prediction = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
```

**I get a different result.** What could it be due to?

Comment: `cv2` reads in `BGR` by default. Are you sure you are sending `RGB` image to the network?

Comment: I added img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) but it still reports a different output

Answer (score 0):

Keras' ImageDataGenerator [uses PIL and not openCV under the hood](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L78) to load and resize images. While you are resizing with bilinear interpolation (the [default](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) for cv2.resize), ImageDataGenerator uses nearest neighbour interpolation by default.

You can play with your resizing method until you get the same result, or use the [`load_img`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L78) and [`img_to_array`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L277) convenience functions from keras-preprocessing to make sure you are doing the exact same preprocessing as was done during training:

```
from keras.prepropressing.image import load_img, img_to_array

img = load_img(path_to_img, target_size=(100, 120)
img = img_to_array(img) / 255.
model.predict(img)
```

Comment: With this setup it works, but is there a way to leverage keras preprocessing library with an image that has already been loaded and has gone through some prior preprocessing steps (e.g. denoising etc.)

Comment: Yes, you can go back and forth between a numpy array and a PIL Image with `img_to_array` and `array_to_img` from keras preprocessing, and do the resizing with PIL's Image.resize() method, in the same way as in `load_img() `

Comment: If i save and reload the preprocessed image using load_img it works, if I use     img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    img = array_to_img(img)
    img = img.resize((100, 120), Image.NEAREST)
    img = img_to_array(img) / 255. 
    img = np.reshape(img, [1, 100, 120, 3]) IT DOESN'T

Comment: In what sense does it not work? Do you get an error message, or just different results?

Comment: I get different results